# How can i solve virtualbox problem? ubuntu-14.04

Tags: virtualbox

This is the problem:

[image: 1]

i want to install kali linux in virtual box.everything ok when i turn on then displayed this.

Comment: What do you read from the error logs mentioned in the message?

Comment: What is the operating system you installing 32bit or 64bit, what are your  VM settings.

Comment: i am useing 64 bit

Comment: what are your VM settings ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Guru Meditation

From the [Virtual Box manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html):

> A VM runs into a Guru Meditation if there is a problem which cannot be fixed by other means than terminating the process.

This error is displayed by default whenever a guest can not be executed. Now this can have many different reasons. Usually the virtual box log files in the machine's directory (in your case in `~/Virtual Box VMs/kalilinox01/Logs/` will tell you all details needed to fix the issue.

In the best case it was simply running out of memory, which could be solved by assigning enough RAM to the VM. Not all physical RAM available should be assigned. We should leave enough RAM for the host to operate, and we should also take the virtual video RAM into account.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Guru Meditation error appeared every time I tried to update my Lubuntu 18.04 machine, in VirtualBox 6.04. It was associated with the following Vbox.log error:

```
00:04:13.601 Not in text mode!
00:04:13.601 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Following the suggestion described here: [Not in Text Mode! Error (guest Windows PE 3.0)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=44208), about *activating I/O APIC in the virtual machine configuration*, the problem was solved.